# .replace('\n','') not working to remove \n from string that is taken from pandas df

Tags: python

In the following string

```
SHANTELL'S CHANNEL - https://www.youtube.com/shantellmartin\nCANDICE - https://www.lovebilly.com\n\nfilmed this video in 4k on this -- http://amzn.to/2sTDnRZ\nwith this lens -- http://amzn.to/2rUJOmD\nbig drone -   http://amzn.to/2o3GLX5\nSony CAMERA http://amzn.to/2nOBmnv\nOLD CAMERA; http://amzn.to/2o2cQBT\nMAIN LENS; http://amzn.to/2od5gBJ\nBIG SONY CAMERA; http://amzn.to/2nrdJRO\nBIG Canon CAMERA; on http://instagram.com/caseyneistat\non https://www.facebook.com/cneistat\non https://twitter.com/CaseyNeistat\n\namazing intro song by https://soundcloud.com/discoteeth\n\nad disclosure.  THIS IS NOT AN AD.  not selling or promoting anything.  but samsung did produce the Shantell Video as a 'GALAXY PROJECT' which is an initiative that enables creators like Shantell and me to make projects we might otherwise not have the opportunity to make.  hope that's clear.  if not ask in the comments and i'll answer any specifics.
```

I am trying to remove any \n. This string is accessed from a pandas df. The solution I have tried is:

```
i = str(i).replace("\n", "")
```

The original code looks like:

```
for i in data["description"]:
    print(i)
    i = str(i).replace("\n", "")
    i = str(i).split(" ")
    for x in i:
        x = x.replace("\n", "")
        print(x)
```

where data is the df that stores all of the data from the csv file, and description is the column where the string is taken out of.
I suspect that the failure of replace() to work is due to the string being from a df, as when I try it with just a regular string

```
x = "a \n\n string"
```

.replace() works just fine. Any reason why taking strings from a df causes replace to fail? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly does _"... causes replace to fail"_ mean?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas Dataframes keep their string methods a bit hidden behind the `.str` attribute.  Something like `df["column_name"].str.replace("\n", "")` should work, and I'd recommend the pandas documentation below to learn more.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#string-methods

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df["description"].str.replace("\n", "")
```

Or you could use either of the following if you want to do this for the entire df:

```
df = df.replace("\n", "")
df.replace("\n", "", inplace = True)
```